# handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued

Tags: c++, exception

I am kind of new to C++ and I am having some trouble with my code.

Part of my code is that I am trying to assign an ID number to a big number of points that have three coordinates. I have a struct of the points. Number is the number of points that I have. They are a lot and I got them from a file. This is what I am doing:

```
struct point{
int coord[3];
float color;
};
points *point = new point[100000];



int d=0;
for (int x = 0; x < number; x++){
for (int y = 0; y < number; y++){
    for (int z = 0; z < number; z++){
    point[d].coord[0] = x;
    point[d].coord[1] = y;
    point[d].coord[2] = z;
    d++;
    }
 }
```

This works for small number, but when I put the actual number of points that I have it gives me this error:
First-chance exception at 0x00E46CD8 in CIS560_HW1a.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x01470000.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

I have no idea what this means and I cant figure out whats wrong with my program. I know the other parts work well cuz I just get the error when I have this part.

Comment: Hint: how often is `d++` called?

Comment: If you're new to C++, might I suggest to use [`std::vector<point> points(100000);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of `point *points = new point[100000];`?

Comment: d++ is called after each iteration...what do you mean? And I know I can do vectors but I have to do it with array :/

Comment: "each iteration" yes, but more precisely. You can figure that out where your error comes from! There are multiple loops, so what is "each iteration" and how many of them are there for a specific value of `number`? (Oh, and using `new` and raw pointers is really old-fashioned C++. Unfortunate that it's still considered basic and so important by some.)

Comment: So x, y and z are supposed to go from 0 to 100, so I have a total of 10000 points that I have to assign to IDs.

Comment: Just look at the three loops, forget about the assignment of the coordinates for a moment. There are three loops, each go from 0 to `number`. So after the loops, what's the value of `d`?

Comment: Okay, so after the loops d should be the total number of points that I have. Or at least that is what I am trying to do...I am trying to increase the ID number...

Comment: Yes, that's what you trying to do, but it's not what you're doing. The body of each loop is executed `number` times. So, the body of the innermost loop (with the variable `z`) is executed `number` times, and each iteration of it increments `d` by one. But it's nested in the middle loop (with variable `y`), therefore the innermost loop itself is run `number` times, each time running its loop body `number` times. So, at the end, `d++` has been executed `number*number*number` times, and `d` has exactly this value. You're accessing the array out-of-bounds, which is causing the access violation.

Comment: Okay yes, i understand what you are saying. Thank you ! But..then I cant think of a way of doing what I was trying..Do u have any hints?

Comment: What is `number`? Is `number*number*number` greater than 100000? If so, you are trying to access the array out of bounds, which will cause undefined behavior (in this case, the access violation).

Comment: NUmber is exacty is 100.But i thought the point of declaring the array with pointer was to be able to change the size.

Comment: Wow, I must be too tired ;) your code is actually correct if you want to assign a unique coordinate to each point, where each axis (x,y,z) is in 0..100. However, you have to watch out that `number` must be the cube root of the amount of points, in other words the amount of points must be `number*number*number`. For `number == 100`, the amount of points must be `1000000` (1e2^3 = 1e6, i.e. 1 million, your amount of points is only 100,000).

Comment: haha oh okay ! So my question now is, I thought that declaring the array the way i did i was able to change its size..is that correct?

Comment: That's actually worth another question on SO. I fear we're already heavily polluting the comment section, which is not intended for this kind of discussion.